# Payroll company advertising for job with typo in salary

Tags: discussion, bug

This made me laugh. The salary range is $90,000 - 1,400,000. I'm thinking they accidentally put an extra zero on the high end of that range.

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104723/software-engineer-full-stack-justworks

[image]

Pretty funny for a company that handles payroll. Is there a way to report potential issues like this to the company?

Comment: *I wouldn't wait and get that job!*

Comment: Maybe it's a "test".

Comment: @flyingL123 Looks like it's a real company. Do you mean maybe the company was testing things out?

Comment: I was joking that it's some sort of test to see who finds the error. Find the error, get the job.

Comment: Not a bug, and not a topic for discussion here. The *bug* tag refers to an issue with this site, and *discussion* refers to discussing issues or topics related to this site, not discussion of other things you think are amusing. Sorry, but tags have specific meanings here.

Comment: Apologies. At the end of the question I asked if there was a way to inform the author about the potential issue with their job posting. That's what I was looking to discuss, not whether or not this was amusing.